# How do you land safely at the beginning of the game?

Tags: just-cause-2

In the beginning after getting the map from Joe I have to land safely but the problem is the parachute won`t open?

Every time I tried I get killed. How to land safely without using parachute?

Comment: PC (which controller), 360 or PS3?

Comment: check your controls - parachute is A on xbox, X on playstation and spacebar on PC

Comment: Yeah, have you *tried* to open it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can fire your grappling hook into the ground. It's a bit counter intuitive but it's a video game.

Comment: How to fire your grappling hook into the ground.

Comment: Target the ground, and fire the hook by pressing the key/button assigned to it. I guess.

Comment: What Ealhad said